# how to store json response locally (sqflite database) in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, sqflite

I did not able to store json response from API in sqflite database but i already parsed json response in list and also i stored similar data in sqflite database.

To stored locally i got success and able to perform CRUD operation and sending it to server, similarly i also able to perform CRUD operation on API data but problem arises on synchronization  between local and json data.

the below code id for calling json data

```
Future<List<Activities>> getData() async {
List<Activities> list;
var res = await http
    .post("http://xxxx/get-activity", headers: {
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer " + _token.toString()
});
if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = json.decode(res.body);
  var rest = data["data"] as List;
 // print(rest);
  list = rest.map<Activities>((json) => Activities.fromJson(json)).toList();
 // print('okay, ${rest[0]}!');
} else {
  print('something error');
}
print("List Size: ${list.length}");
return list;
```

}

Comment: Do you mean you have a json string and you want to save this large string to sqlite? or you have parsed this json string and want to save each fields to sqllite?

Comment: i did this. my actual problem at that time is : i parsed json string and able to display in list using future builder and problem store locally in sqflite

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
var data = json.decode(res.body);
var activities= data["data"] as List; 
for (var activity in activities) {
 Activity actData = Activity.fromMap(activity);
 batch.insert(actTable, actData.toMap());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution! Please use this flutter plugin [json_store](https://pub.dev/packages/json_store)